# How to use node-config in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-config

After installing `node-config` and `@types/config`:

```
yarn add config
yarn add --dev @types/config
```

And adding config as described in [lorenwest/node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config):

```
// default.ts
export default {
  server: {
    port: 4000,
  },
  logLevel: 'error',
};
```

When I am trying to use in my app:

```
import config from 'config';

console.log(config.server);
```

I am getting the error:

```
src/app.ts(19,53): error TS2339: Property 'server' does not exist on type 'IConfig'.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`config.get` utility can be used to get the config values like so:

```
import config from 'config';

const port: number = config.get('server.port');
```

Comment: It is just a workaround. still looking for better answer.

Comment: This is how config is expected to be used. `get` and `has` are actual reasons to use it. It provides too much magic to be properly typed. You could extend its type like `const config: IConfig & MySchema = require('config')` or with custom d.ts typing, but you cannot be sure that expected properties are there because they can exist in one config but not in another.

Comment: Not sure what a "better answer" would look like, but it's important to note that `config.get()` supports generics.

You could do `config.get<number>('server.port')` and that might be a little cleaner in some instances.

Comment: automatic typing could be certainly implemented in the library using ts template litterals

Comment: I have many reasons to use JSON format for the config file, but I encountered several issues after switching my NodeJS project to typescript; the trick explained by @Fedoranimus fixed some, thanks

Answer (score 19):

I'm taking a slightly different approach - defining the variables in JavaScript, and accessing them in TypeScript.

Using the following folder structure:

```
├── config
│   ├── custom-environment-variables.js
│   ├── default.js
│   ├── development.js
│   └── production.js
└── server
    ├── config.ts
    └── main.ts
```

I define the configuration in the root `config/` folder. For example:

```js
// config/default.js
module.exports = {
  cache: false,
  port: undefined  // Setting to undefined ensures the environment config must define it
};

// config/development.js
module.exports = {
  port: '3000'
}

// config/production.js
module.exports = {
  cache: true
}

// config/custom-environment-variables.js
module.exports = {
  port: 'PORT'
}
```

Now, in TypeScript land, I define an interface to provide nicer autocomplete & documentation, and write some bridging code to pull in the config from `node-config` into my config map:

```
// server/config.ts
import nodeConfig from 'config';

interface Config {
  /** Whether assets should be cached or not. */
  cache: boolean;

  /** The port that the express server should bind to. */
  port: string;
}

const config: Config = {
  cache: nodeConfig.get<boolean>('cache'),
  port: nodeConfig.get<string>('port')
};

export default config;
```

Finally, I can now import and use my config variables inside any TypeScript code.

```
// server/main.ts
import express from 'express';
import config from './config';

const { port } = config;

const app = express();

app.listen(port);
```

This approach has the following benefits:

- We can use the rich and battle-tested features available from `node-config` without needing to re-invent the wheel
- We have a strongly-typed, well documented config map which can be imported and used from anywhere inside our TS code

Answer (score 12):

Use this "import * as config from 'config';" instead of "import config from 'config';"

```
    import * as config from 'config';

    const port = config.get('server.port');
    console.log('port', port);
    // port 4000
```

config/development.json

```
    {
      "server": {
          "port": 4000
      }
    }
```

and set NODE_ENV=development

```
 export NODE_ENV=development
```

note: No need this NODE_ENV set if you use default

Answer (score 5):

From the previous, I was still having trouble where `config` was not able to find the `server` key from `default.ts`.

Below is how I am using npm config module. Updated `export default {` to `export =`:

```
// default.ts
export = {
  server: {
    port: 4000,
  },
  logLevel: 'error',
};
```

Usage within the app [Same]:

```
import config from 'config';

console.log(config.get('server'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could make this work is by uninstalling `@types/config` and modifying the type definitions to include my config files.

`config.d.ts`

```
    declare module 'config' {
    
      // Importing my config files
      import dev from '#config/development.json'
      import test from '#config/test.json'
      import prod from '#config/production.json'
    
      // Creating a union of my config
      type Config = typeof dev | typeof test | typeof prod
    
      var c: c.IConfig;
    
      namespace c {
    
        // see https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Using-Config-Utilities
        interface IUtil {
            // Extend an object (and any object it contains) with one or more objects (and objects contained in them).
            extendDeep(mergeInto: any, mergeFrom: any, depth?: number): any;
    
            // Return a deep copy of the specified object.
            cloneDeep(copyFrom: any, depth?: number): any;
    
            // Return true if two objects have equal contents.
            equalsDeep(object1: any, object2: any, dept?: number): boolean;
    
            // Returns an object containing all elements that differ between two objects.
            diffDeep(object1: any, object2: any, depth?: number): any;
    
            // Make a javascript object property immutable (assuring it cannot be changed from the current value).
            makeImmutable(object: any, propertyName?: string, propertyValue?: string): any;
    
            // Make an object property hidden so it doesn't appear when enumerating elements of the object.
            makeHidden(object: any, propertyName: string, propertyValue?: string): any;
    
            // Get the current value of a config environment variable
            getEnv(varName: string): string;
    
            // Return the config for the project based on directory param if not directory then return default one (config).
            loadFileConfigs(configDir?: string): any;
    
            // Return the sources for the configurations
            getConfigSources(): IConfigSource[];
            
            // Returns a new deep copy of the current config object, or any part of the config if provided.
            toObject(config?: any): any;
    
            /**
             * This allows module developers to attach their configurations onto
             * the 6 years agoInitial 0.4 checkin default configuration object so
             * they can be configured by the consumers of the module.
             */
            setModuleDefaults(moduleName:string, defaults:any): any;
        }
    
        interface IConfig {
            // Changed the get method definition.
            get<K extends keyof Config>(setting: K): Config[K];
            has(setting: string): boolean;
            util: IUtil;
        }
    
        interface IConfigSource {
            name: string;
            original?: string;
            parsed: any;
        }
      }
    
      export = c;
    
    }
```

Then I can do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the biggest drawback of type safety is that it can create a false sense of security due to the common confusion between compile-time safety and runtime safety. It is especially true for node-config where the config is the product of merging multiple files and environment variables. This is why any solution that applies a type to your config without checking that it actually maps that type at runtime can create problems down the line. To solve this you could have a look at type guarding solutions like [typia](https://github.com/samchon/typia) or [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) for example.

Personally I use tools that are usually already present in my projects : [JTD](https://jsontypedef.com/) + [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org/). Here is a recipe if somebody is interested.

```
config
├── config.jtd.json
├── custom-environment-variables.js
├── default.json
└── development.json
src
├── config.ts
types
└── index.ts
```

The file `config/config.jtd.json` is written by hand, it looks like this (optionalProperties is used to ignore some things added by node-config, merging the interface with IConfig provided by node-config might be a better way to do the same thing):

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "port": { "type": "uint32"}
  },
  "optionalProperties": { "util": {}, "get": {}, "has": {} }
}
```

The file `types/index.ts` contains a `Config` interface, it was created using [jtd-codegen](https://github.com/jsontypedef/json-typedef-codegen):

```bash
jtd-codegen config/config.jtd.json --typescript-out types
```

Then `src/config.ts` performs the validation and type casting:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import config from 'config'
import Ajv from 'ajv/dist/jtd'
import { type Config } from '../types'

const validate = new Ajv().compile(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config/config.jtd.json', 'utf8')))
if (!validate(config)) throw new Error('invalid config', { cause: validate.errors })

config.util.makeImmutable(config)
const typedConfig = config as unknown as Config

export default typedConfig
```

Now when importing `src/config.ts` you have both compile-time type safety and runtime validation no matter what. The config object is also immutable so it will stay safe. Note that the config.get method is not covered, but I don't think it is necessary now that safety is ensured. You might even remove it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative 1

Use [node-config-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-config-ts)

#### Alternative 2

node-config-ts only updates the types every time you `npm i`, but alternative 2 is good if you want to be more explicit about which configuration files you are reading from, as they are imported directly in your project. This also means that tools such as [nx](https://nx.dev/) knows to recompile your project if the config files change.

src/Config.ts

```
import config from 'config';
import DefaultConfig from '../config/default';
import CustomEnvironmentVariables from '../config/custom-environment-variables.json';
// If you have more configuration files (eg. production.ts), you might want to add them here.

export const Config = config.util.toObject() as typeof DefaultConfig & typeof CustomEnvironmentVariables;
```

src/app.ts

```
import {Config} from './Config';

// Has the correct type of "string"
console.log(Config.server);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    // add these if you want to import .json configs
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
}
```

If you are using a monorepo and try to import `default.ts` in a child project, you might get the error...

```
error TS6059: File 'config/default.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'my-project'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files`.
```

...then you might have to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/5936629).

Answer (score 0):

`node-config` does not detect your config types. `IConfig` is simply the description of the config library interface.

You can tell typescript what type you are expecting by using the "get" method with a type argument like this:

```
const server = config.get<string>("server");
```

NOTE: `config.get` throws an error if your config value is missing. This is intentional to help catch bugs.

If you prefer runtime safety, check for the existence of a config value with the "has" method.

`config.has("server")`

`config.has("api.url")` for nested parameters

However, if your config value turns out to be a different type, such as an object or number instead of a string, you could run into other runtime problems.

Validate with a pattern something like this:

```
const maybeServer = config.has("server") ? config.get("server") : null;

const server = typeof maybeServer === "string" ? maybeServer : "default";
```

After validating in this way, typescript will know your variable's type.

That's the "simple" answer.

For a more comprehensive, enterprise-level solution, use a schema validator like [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod).

Answer (score -4):

You can use the `any` return type.

```
const serverConfig: any = config.get('server');
```

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQkxIszY5AfWuVGQiIoYwbNISEIO3iofMt9AA&usqp=CAU