# How to use node-config in typescript with custom config interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-config

This is a follow up to [How to use node-config in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813591/how-to-use-node-config-in-typescript) since I couldn't find a proper answer.

I'm relatively new to TS and I'm trying to convert our configs from json to typescript, while trying to incorporate types on the config.

What we currently have is something like:

```
// default.json
{
  "server": {
    "timeout": 10
  }
}

// some-code.ts
import config from 'config';
...
const serverTimeout = config.get<number>('server.timeout'); // 10
```

Here, we are able to get required configs, but we need to specify the type via generics in code. I'm trying to incorporate (relatively) stronger typing.

Dry conversion:

```
// default.ts
import { MyConfig } from './config-schema.ts'

const conf: MyConfig = {
  "server": {
    "timeout": 10
  }
};

export default conf;

// config-schema.ts
export interface MyConfig {
  server: {
    timeout: number;
  }
}

// some-code.ts
import config from 'config';

console.log(config); // { "server": { "timeout": 10 } }
console.log(config.get<number>('server.timeout')); // 10
console.log((config as any).server.timeout); // 10
console.log(config.server.timeout); // obviously a compile time error.
```

As you can see, the last form will NOT work and results in compile time ERROR. I somehow want `config` to conform to the shape of `MyConfig` so that `config.server.timeout` is possible with strong type `number`.

I need to *somehow* extend the `IConfig` interface with `MyConfig` or force a re-typing of `config` to `IConfig & MyConfig`.

My attempt:

```
// config-schema.ts
import config from 'config';

interface MyConfig {
  server: {
    timeout: number;
  }
}

export (config as any as MyConfig);

// some-code.ts
import config from './config-schema';

console.log(config.server.timeout); // 10
```

This works, but somehow doesn't feel right to me.

**Problems**

- Forced to use `any`... can this be avoided somehow ?
- Need to do something like `import config from '../../core/config-schema';` -> looks ugly, path different for different files, need all project collaborators to follow convention... is it possible to keep it as `import config from 'config';` and have the magic abstracted out ?
- Compile `default.ts` to `default.js` with `tsc`at compile time (so that typescript is not a runtime dependency). Have updated env var `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` accordingly. Currently I do this, but the config object gets created with an extra hierarchy level. i.e. instead of `config.server.timeout`, it became `config.default.server.timeout`

Edit: Third question resolved -- see comment

Comment: For secondary part: I was able to do static compilation and set typescript as a devDependency. At app start, I set `process.env.NODE_CONFIG_DIR = __dirname + '/dist/config/';` for reading configs from the right location.
Note: since config library now sees JS files, it expects syntax for JS config files, i.e. ends with `module.exports = configObject`. Hence in the TS file we need to do `export = configObject` rather than `export default configObject` since the latter produces JS equivalent to `exports.default = configObject` and that adds an extra `default` hierarchy level in the built config

Comment: Experiment using `console.log(JSON.stringify(config))` in code to see stuff